# How to use windows created by the Dataset.window() method in TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to create a dataset that will return random windows from a time series, along with the next value as the target, using TensorFlow 2.0.

I'm using `Dataset.window()`, which looks promising:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.range(10))
dataset = dataset.window(5, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
for window in dataset:
    print([elem.numpy() for elem in window])
```

Outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

However, I would like to use the last value as the target. If each window was a tensor, I would use:

```py
dataset = dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1:]))
```

However, if I try this, I get an exception:

```py
TypeError: '_VariantDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The solution is to call `flat_map()` like this:

```py
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(5))
```

Now each item in the dataset is a window, so you can split it like this:

```py
dataset = dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1:]))
```

So the full code is:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.range(10))
dataset = dataset.window(5, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(5))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1:]))

for X, y in dataset:
    print("Input:", X.numpy(), "Target:", y.numpy())
```

Which outputs:

```py
Input: [0 1 2 3] Target: [4]
Input: [1 2 3 4] Target: [5]
Input: [2 3 4 5] Target: [6]
Input: [3 4 5 6] Target: [7]
Input: [4 5 6 7] Target: [8]
Input: [5 6 7 8] Target: [9]
```

Comment: Even though it's not necessary for answering the question, could you elaborate on WHY we need this flat_map step? I'm still struggling to understand it.

Comment: The window() method returns a dataset containing windows, where each window is itself represented as a dataset. Something like {{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},...}, where {...} represents a dataset. But we just want a regular dataset containing tensors: {[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],...}, where [...] represents a tensor. The flat_map() method returns all the tensors in a nested dataset, after transforming each nested dataset. If we didn't batch, we would get: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...}. By batching each window to its full size, we get {[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],...} as we desired. Clear?

Comment: Is there a way to then make mini-batches of these samples? We already have a None dimension from window.batch(5), thus when adding e.g. dataset.batch(3), then we get another None dimension

Comment: Ok it actually works, as the None dimension invoked by window.batch is of course necessary.

Comment: you will lose the ability of `len()` by using `flat_map`, but you can use the slow version of `len(list(dataset))` instead

Comment: How Can I use this if my dataset comes from a dictionary? i.e dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(some_dict)