# How to Window Tensorflow Dataset derived from a dictionary

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I would like to window a dataset as seen in the post [How to use windows created by the Dataset.window() method in TensorFlow 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429307/how-to-use-windows-created-by-the-dataset-window-method-in-tensorflow-2-0). However I have multiple features and the dataset derives from a dictionary:

```
import tensorflow as tf
data = {'col_a': [0,1,2,3,4], 'col_b': [0,1,2,3,4]}
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
windowed_ds = ds.window(size=3,shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
new_ds = windowed_ds.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(3))
```

This throws error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'batch'`. I understand the error that instead of a dataset I am dealing with a dictionary however I don't know how to work around it.

My desired output is a dataset of the form: `{'col_a': [[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]], 'col_b': [[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]}`

EDIT: A simplified expression for rushv89's answer would be:

```
windowed_ds.flat_map(lambda window: tf.data.Dataset.zip({k:v.batch(3) for (k, v) in window.items()}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this within `tf.data` API as follows,

```
import tensorflow as tf
data = {'col_a': [0,1,2,3,4], 'col_b': [0,1,2,3,4]}
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)

# Seems like you don't need windows with < 3, then set drop_remainder to True
windowed_ds = ds.window(size=3,shift=1, drop_remainder=True)

# The line that changed
new_ds = windowed_ds.flat_map(lambda window: tf.data.Dataset.zip(
    dict([(k, v.batch(5)) for k, v in window.items()])
))
```

Comment: Thanks so much this is what I was looking for. I'm going to check out your book!

Comment: Thank you! :) One thing I may note is the use of `.batch()` here. It doesn't have an effect beyond a size `3` (which is your window size). This `.batch()` function batches data inside the window from what I understand. If you need batching in the outer scope, you need something like `new_ds.batch(x)`.

Comment: I believe you do need the batch() function otherwise the resultant dataset will no longer be windowed it will be completely flattened. You can see it used in the link I posted in the question.

Comment: Yes, you definitely do need `batch` in the window function (otherwise you'd have only a single element in each window). What I'm saying is that, if you want to batch the windows themselves, you'd need another batch function in the outer scope.

Comment: Ah yes agree completely.